# android/java: cannot parse existing XML file? (mac)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am making a simple android application and I am having issues parsing a simple XML file.
I get the FileNotFoundException even through the file exists and I have all the permissions for it. I tried to modify the path in all the possible ways but I always get this exception thrown.

here's my code
in the main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Engine engine = new Engine();
engine.parse();
```

}

in the engine class:

```
 public void parse() {
            try {

                File fXmlFile = new File("/res/XML/users.xml");
                if (!fXmlFile.exists()) {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to find file: " + 
                            fXmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    ...
```

it really looks simple but I can't get this to work. any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So did I understand correctly, the file is not found? I'm just wondering can you point to files outside of the emulator like you're trying to - or should the xml file reside within emulator file structure instead.

Comment: where can you see /Users/jon___davis/Desktop/users.xml on your device or simulator?

Comment: pasted the wrong string. the file is in res/XML but the situation doesn't change..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a file out of the Resources you can use one of two calls.

Check out. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

You can use `context.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.users)`

This will return an input stream allowing you to read the file.

Alternatively you can call `context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.users)`

This will return an XML Resource parser, this is a pullParser that will allow you to parse the xml.